# D3: Why tooltip near cursor never shows?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm trying to make a d3 tooltip that can show near my cursor when I hover over a dot. I tried lots of methods available online, but none of them works. The tooltip doesn't show, and there is no error messages in console. Could anyone help me with this? My code is as follows:

I suspect there might be some issue with svg, but not sure how to solve it.

```
var svg = d3.select("#linechart").append("svg").attr('id','cases')
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
    .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");


var xScale = d3.scaleTime()
    .domain(d3.extent(getCovidDate(data,state), function(d){return new Date(d)}))
    .range([0, width]);


var yScale = d3.scaleLinear()
    .domain(d3.extent(getCases(data,state), function(d){return d}))
    .range([height, 0]);


var line = d3.line()
    .x(function(d) { return xScale(new Date(d[0])); }) // set the x values for the line generator
    .y(function(d) { return yScale(d[1]); }) // set the y values for the line generator
    .curve(d3.curveMonotoneX) // apply smoothing to the line

var dataset = d3.zip(getCovidDate(data,state),getCases(data,state))


svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "x axis")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
    .call(d3.axisBottom(xScale)); // Create an axis component with d3.axisBottom


svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "y axis")
    .call(d3.axisLeft(yScale)); // Create an axis component with d3.axisLeft

var div = d3.select("#cases").append("div")
    .attr("class", "tooltip")
    .style("display", "none");


svg.append("path")
    .datum(dataset) // Binds data to the line
    .attr("class", "line") // Assign a class for styling
    .attr("d", line)  // Calls the line generator
    .style('fill-opacity', 0)
    .style('stroke','cadetblue')
    .on('mouseover', function (d, i) {
        d3.select(this).transition()
            .duration('50')
            .attr('opacity', '.55')})
    .on('mouseout', function (d, i) {
        d3.select(this).transition()
            .duration('50')
            .attr('opacity', '1')});

svg.selectAll(".dot")
    .data(dataset)
    .enter().append("circle") 
    .attr("class", "dot") // Assign a class for styling
    .attr("cx", function(d) { return xScale(new Date(d[0])) })
    .attr("cy", function(d) { return yScale(d[1]) })
    .attr("r", 5)
    .style("fill",'cadetblue')
    .on('mouseover', function (d, i) {
        d3.select(this).transition()
            .duration('50')
            .attr('opacity', '.55')
        
        div.style("display", "inline");
    })
    .on('mousemove',function(d){
        div.text(d[1])
            .style("left", (d3.event.pageX + 10) + "px")
            .style("top", (d3.event.pageY - 15) + "px")
    })
    .on('mouseout', function (d, i) {
            d3.select(this).transition()
                .duration('50')
                .attr('opacity', '1')
            div.style("display", "none");
            
    });

svg.append("line")
    .attr("x1", xScale(new Date(inputValue)))
    .attr("y1", 0)
    .attr("x2", xScale(new Date(inputValue)))
    .attr("y2", height)
    .style("stroke-width", 2)
    .style("stroke", "red")
    .style("fill", "none");

    d3.select('#cases').remove()
```

Comment: Can you provide a complete [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) example?

Comment: Preferably a stack snippet using StackOverflow snippets, JSFiddle links die or get stale

Comment: You append `div` (tooltip) to `#cases`, and then, at the end of the script, you remove `cases#`. Isn't this the problem?